# the client is unable to receive the stack-trace of the exception from the server

Tags: java, ajax, reactjs, web-services, client-server

The code posted below is a client-server code that throws http 500 error which is because of some exception thrown by the server. I actually want to send the exception (produced at server side) to the client in order to know the reason for http 500 error. For sending the stack-trace, I am using this line `return Response.status(200).entity(err).build();` but nothing is being printed at the client side. Please see my code and tell me that how can I get from the server the stack-trace of thrown exception?

**ReactJS Client:**

```
saveChanges(newRecordsArray) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/myService/save",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType:'application/json',
            data: newRecordsArray,
            async: false
        }).then((function(err) {
            {console.log(err);}
        }).bind(this));
    }
```

**Java Service:**

```
@POST
    @Path("/save")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response saveNewRecords(JSONArray newRecordsArray) {
        try {
            File recordsFile = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\myJSON.txt");
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(recordsFile);
            fileWriter.write(newRecordsArray.toString());
            fileWriter.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            String err = e.getClass().toString();
            return Response.status(200).entity(err).build();
        }
        return Response.status(200).entity(newRecordsArray.toString()).build();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you sending 200 OK in the catch block? Are you actually getting the stacktrace in the first place? I don't think so, at least with that code.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you get only the exception message is because `Response.status(200).entity(err).build()` calls the `toString()` method on your exception object.

If you would like to get the full stack trace as a String then I suggest you to use an external library which helps you to do the job.

Apache Commons Lang library could be a perfect choice. This is the static method you need to use:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e)
```

You can find more details about this method [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.html).

I suggest you to send back HTTP500 instead of HTTP200:

```
String exceptionString = ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e);
Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(exceptionString).build();
```